# Linqtoxml, I cant seem to grab any elements in my document

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML file, its SCORM for learning management system and I am having real problems with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest identifier="Privacy101" version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2"
    xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2       imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd">
<metadata>
    <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
    <schemaversion>1.2</schemaversion>
    <lom xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemalocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd">
        <general>
            <title>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Privacy 101</langstring>
            </title>
            <catalogentry>
                <catalog>Macromedia Captivate Course</catalog>
                <entry>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Privacy101</langstring>
                </entry>
            </catalogentry>
            <description>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">A quick course on Internet Privacy</langstring>
            </description>
            <keyword>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none"></langstring>
            </keyword>
        </general>
        <lifecycle>
            <version>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">1.0</langstring>
            </version>
            <status>
                <source>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">LOMv1.0</langstring>
                </source>
                <value>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Final</langstring>
                </value>
            </status>
        </lifecycle>
        <metametadata>
            <metadatascheme>ADL SCORM 1.2</metadatascheme>
        </metametadata>
        <technical>
            <format>text/html</format>
            <location>.</location>
        </technical>
        <educational>
            <typicallearningtime>
                <datetime>00:05:00</datetime>
            </typicallearningtime>
        </educational>
        <rights>
            <cost>
                <source>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">LOMv1.0</langstring>
                </source>
                <value>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">no</langstring>
                </value>
            </cost>
            <copyrightandotherrestrictions>
                <source>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">LOMv1.0</langstring>
                </source>
                <value>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">no</langstring>
                </value>
            </copyrightandotherrestrictions>
        </rights>
        <classification>
            <purpose>
                <source>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">LOMv1.0</langstring>
                </source>
                <value>
                    <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Idea</langstring>
                </value>
            </purpose>
            <description>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">A quick course on Internet Privacy</langstring>
            </description>
            <keyword>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Macromedia Captivate</langstring>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none"></langstring>
            </keyword>
        </classification>
    </lom>
</metadata>
<organizations default="Privacy101_ORG">
    <organization identifier="Privacy101_ORG">
        <title>Privacy 101</title>
        <item identifier="P1" isvisible="true" identifierref="P1_RES">
            <title>Browser Options</title>
            <adlcp:maxtimeallowed></adlcp:maxtimeallowed>
            <adlcp:datafromlms></adlcp:datafromlms>
            <adlcp:masteryscore>80</adlcp:masteryscore>
            <adlcp:timelimitaction>exit,message</adlcp:timelimitaction>
        </item>
    </organization>
</organizations>
<resources>
    <resource identifier="P1_RES" type="webcontent" href="Simulation.htm" adlcp:scormtype="sco">
        <file href="Simulation.swf"/>
        <file href="Simulation.htm"/>
        <file href="SCORM_support/scorm_support.htm"/>
        <file href="SCORM_support/scorm_support.js"/>
        <file href="SCORM_support/scorm_support.swf"/>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

My first problem is that I cant seem to get hold of any of the elements. I have tried a few methods but would like to use linqtoxml if possible.

I have tried the code below :

```
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Stephen Liversidge\Desktop\SCORM Examples\1.2\cookies\unzipped\imsmanifest.xml");

        var lv1s = from docEls in xdoc.Root.Elements("manifest")
                   select docEls;
```

I am having no joy though, no matter what element I try to attach too, I get an enumeration yeilded no results method.

I have a feeling this is an easy one, but I am struggling to get a start point.

Could you help please.

thanks

Stephen

Comment: (Elements and Descendants both work the same way in terms of namespaces, so don't worry that the duplicate question talks about Descendants.)

Comment: Your xml seems to be ill-formed by the way.<Manifest> doesn't have closing tag.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, thats really helpful, exactly what I was after.